# Can I create an in-memory database with SqlDelight for running in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, sqldelight

I have a SqlDelight database that is working nicely. I create it like this:

```
Database(AndroidSqliteDriver(Database.Schema, context, DatabaseName)
```

For unit-tests, I create an in-memory database like this:

```
Database(JdbcSqliteDriver(JdbcSqliteDriver.IN_MEMORY).apply { 
        Database.Schema.create(this) 
})
```

I wanted to do the same for androidTests that run on the emulator or on a physical device, but JdbcSqliteDriver doesn't work in Android, presumably because Android doesn't have that package installed by default.

How do I run an in-memory database in AndroidTest (or in production)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out if you don't name your database, it creates an in-memory version:

```
Database(AndroidSqliteDriver(Database.Schema, context, null)
```

Because `AndroidSqliteDriver` uses `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Builder` which has this in the documentation:

```
    /**
     * @param name Name of the database file, or null for an in-memory database.
     * @return This
     */
    @NonNull
    public Builder name(@Nullable String name) {
        mName = name;
        return this;
    }
```